# Aggregating values in "virtual" columns created with table constructor within a measure

Tags: powerbi, dax

within a measure I am creating a "virtual" table with several rows and columns. Within the same measure I need to aggregate the values from one of the resulting columns.

My problem is that I can't figure out how to access/refer to a column of the resulting virtual table with aggregator functions like e.g. MAX() or SUM().

Here is the code for creating the table within a measure (= it is **not** a calculated table in the datamodel):

```
VAR virtualtable =
        {
             ( "o1", 1, 2, 3 ),
             ( "o2", 4, 5, 6 ),
             ( "o4", 7, 8, 9 ),
             ( "o5", 10, 11, 12 )
        }
```

Resulting table:

| Value1 | Value2 | Value3 | Value4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| o1 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| o2 | 4 | 5 | 6 |
| o4 | 7 | 8 | 9 |
| o5 | 10 | 11 | 12 |

Trying to sum the values of column "Value2" using `SUM( virtualtable[Value2] )` does not work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to SUM the column of a table variable is using SUMX, for instance this works

```
Sum Val 2 = 
VAR virtualtable =
        {
             ( "o1", 1, 2, 3 ),
             ( "o2", 4, 5, 6 ),
             ( "o4", 7, 8, 9 ),
             ( "o5", 10, 11, 12 )
        }
RETURN SUMX( virtualtable, [Value2] )
```